# Users > Voters on Meta Page: I cannot be the only one voting this month!

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, voting

I just noticed something extremely strange: on my end, I appear to be the only person that has voted on any Physices.SE Meta Posts this entire month. I'll post a screenshot since this is unbelievable even to myself.

[image]

This is impossible, as I've clearly observed certain questions being upvoted and downvoted recently on this Meta site. The vote-count above matches my vote-count on the Meta end of things from me (21 verses 90 on the regular Physics.SE site), so the issue seems unrelated to any mix-up there.

Is this normal and intentional to only see yourself on this screen, or is this a new bug?

Comment: I noticed other anomalies on those user league pages (not the exact same as here and on another site) for things that *definitely* were different up until a few days or a few weeks ago (having been unchanged for many, many years). So there is a time correlation.

Comment: @PeterMortensen I saw on the main Meta.SE that they’ve been doing some code updates recently, and it’s caused weird errors on meta sites across the various sites. Might be why (personal speculation on my part though).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It seems the [page](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/users?tab=Voters&filter=quarter) is only showing users with $\geq 10$ votes presumably by design.

Comment: Looks like you are right, I checked other Meta sites I'm registered with (like Astronomy.SE) and it's the same behavior. Guess it's not a bug. Feel free to properly retag my question, I'm not so familiar with the Meta's side on this (if it's not too much trouble ofc).

Comment: And there are not very many posts (or votes) per month here on Meta - fortunately.